# How to compare between two objects according to an attribute in js

Tags: javascript, loops

Java script.
I have 2 arrays for example:

```
Array 1 [{name:'danny ro',age:14},{name:'Rose tl', age:17},{name:'Ali ga', age:15}]
Array 2 [{name:'danny',class:A},{name:'Ron', class:D}]
```

I want to compare only by **names** and to find out if array 1 has object with name that **contains** name from Array 2.
To my example I would get this answer :

```
{name:'danny',class:A}
```

I tried nesting loops but I'm looking for something simpler.

Comment: It's always going to be two loops, I think.

Comment: filter+some+includes `array2.filter(e => array1.some(f => f.name.includes(e.name)))`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr1 = [{name:'danny ro',age:14},{name:'Rose tl', age:17},{name:'Ali ga', age:15}]
const arr2 =  [{name:'danny',class:'A'},{name:'Ron', class:'D'}]

const filtered = arr2.filter(user => arr1.some(lookup => lookup.name.includes(user.name)));

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Cleaner method

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` and `Array.prototype.some` to achieve this.

Here's how you could do this:

```
const array1 = [
    {name:'danny ro', age:14},
    {name:'Rose tl', age:17},
    {name:'Ali ga', age:15}
];
const array2 = [
    {name:'danny', class:'A'},
    {name:'Ron', class:'D'}
];

// Create a new array 'result' that includes objects from array2 
// if the 'name' of the object in array2 is included in the 'name' property of any object in array1
const result = array2.filter(obj2 => 
    array1.some(obj1 => obj1.name.includes(obj2.name))
);

console.log(result);
// [{ "name": "danny", "class": "A" }]
```

---

#### Efficient Method

To achieve this task with optimal efficiency, specifically adhering to `O(n)` time complexity, a mapping needs to be created using the names from the initial array.

Here's how you could do this:

```
const array1 = [
    {name:'danny ro', age:14},
    {name:'Rose tl', age:17},
    {name:'Ali ga', age:15}
];

const array2 = [
    {name:'danny', class:'A'},
    {name:'Ron', class:'D'}
];

// Create a name map from array1
const nameMap = {};

array1.forEach(obj => {
    const names = obj.name.split(' ');
    names.forEach(name => {
        nameMap[name] = true;
    });
});

// Filter array2 based on nameMap
const result = array2.filter(obj2 =>
    nameMap[obj2.name]
);

console.log(result);
// [{ "name": "danny", "class": "A" }]
```